# control window.onbeforeunload event

Tags: javascript, jquery

From out of curiosity can i Control window.onbeforeunload event like check if the user decided to leave the page or stay in it and can I raise an alert or some function based on his decision if yes please tell me

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(window).bind("beforeunload",function(){
if(//stay on page)
alert("i want to stay on the page");
else //leave page
 alert("i want to leave the page");
});
</script>
```

I understand that window.onbeforeunload is an event that give the user a message to tell him that maybe you forget to do something before you leave but this quest is just out of curiosity and thank you

Comment: i am just doing some research my goal is not firing an alert message like in the example my goal is to trigger a javascript function that do some javascript code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot get the result of `onbeforeunload`. Also, even if you somehow managed to figure out a way to get the result, you wouldn't be able to raise an alert. You could probably run another function.

> [The `showModalDialog()`, `alert()`, `confirm()` and `prompt()` methods are now allowed to do nothing during `pagehide`, **`beforeunload`** and `unload` events.](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5-diff/#changes-2011-05-25)

Comment: @Sora No, there isn't since browsers haven't implemented a way to do that.

Answer (score 1):

You can ONLY return a string which will show a dialog confirmation displaying the string you returned (But with additional ok/cancel buttons to confirm the action).

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(window).bind("beforeunload",function(){
return 'Are you sure you want to leave this page?';
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Put a timer of one second. Clear it on unload. Should work, but didn't test it.

```
window.addEventListener('beforeunload', function (event) {

  var timeId = setTimeout(yourFunctionIfTheUserStays, 1000);

  window.addEventListener('unload', function (event) {
    clearTimeout(timeId);
  })
  return 'Are you sure you want to leave this page?';
});
```